# Third party icon in google login

Tags: gmail, google-cloud-platform, gmail-api

In google integration with website, at the integration page (or allow the access) two images are to be shown.
One is user profile image and another third party icon. Here what I want to know, what is that third party icon and where I will give that image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upload it at *OAuth consent screen* of your app:

https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials/consent